VictoriaMetrics (VM Agent) relable metrics pattern
I have this config in my vmagent:
global:
  scrape_interval: 60s
  scrape_timeout: 60s
  external_labels:
    server_name: vmagent

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "kafka_exporter"
    file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - kafka_exporter.yml
    metric_relabel_configs:
      - if: '{__name__="kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum"}'
        target_label: foo
        replacement: 3

Im trying to add label to only one metric. There it is:
kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum{consumergroup="test",topic="elk"} 0

But if I search metrics im my VictoriaMetrics (remote write to vmagent), its no-one metrics with this label. Here they are:
sum by(__name__)({__name__=~".+",foo="3"}):

kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum{}
kafka_consumergroup_members{}
kafka_exporter_build_info{}
kafka_topic_partition_current_offset{}
kafka_topic_partition_in_sync_replica{}
kafka_topic_partition_leader{}
kafka_topic_partition_leader_is_preferred{}
kafka_topic_partition_oldest_offset{}
kafka_topic_partition_replicas{}
kafka_topic_partition_under_replicated_partition{}
kafka_topic_partitions{}
process_cpu_seconds_total{}
process_max_fds{}
process_open_fds{}
process_resident_memory_bytes{}
process_start_time_seconds{}
process_virtual_memory_bytes{}
process_virtual_memory_max_bytes{}
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight{}
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{}

What am I doing wrong? Why other metrics have same label?
If I try to do the same for another metric (kafka_topic_partitions), there is no such problem (Its not true! See "p.s."). Config fully same:
      - if: '{__name__="kafka_topic_partitions"}'
        target_label: foo
        replacement: 3

p.s. I found the pattern. Tags are added to all metric after the selected (in example: kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum).
If I select kafka_topic_partitions, then list is:
sum by(__name__)({__name__=~".+",foo="3"}):

kafka_topic_partitions{}
process_cpu_seconds_total{}
process_max_fds{}
process_open_fds{}
process_resident_memory_bytes{}
process_start_time_seconds{}
process_virtual_memory_bytes{}
process_virtual_memory_max_bytes{}
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight{}
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{}

It looks as if works once to determine the cutting point.
How I can add label to only one metric?

Can you explain what makes you think something is incorrect? As far as I can see, everything is as it should be. Presence of kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum in the result of your query says that it has label foo set to 3.

@markalex, I want only one metric has label foo=3, but its about 20. I dont understand why.

Aha, thanks for clarification! Could it be that kafka_exporter.yml contains label foo in it?

Also, quick way to check if your relabel config is a culprit here: change 3 in it, restart server and check result of the query (and the same query, but with 4).

@markalex, that is the reason why foo=3, but not 1 :)
I presented a complete config in the question, label "foo" contains once

@markalex, I found the pattern. Tags are added to all metric after the selected (in example: kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum). Please see "p.s." in question.

Sounds like a bug in VictoriaMetrics. Consider filing an issue in their bug tracker.

@markalex, thanks a lot.
https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/6080

I opend issue on GitHub about similar problem (I wanted to filter metrics, tags was a tool): https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/6080
This is not a bug, it really works like that, it’s just that it is not written anywhere. Not all contributors even know about it, but https://github.com/f41gh7 is a real expert of VM!
In my case its need to use to filter metrics.
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__name__]
      action: keep
      regex: '^kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum$'

This does not answer how to add tags, but for me the question is resolved. It is not difficult to figure it out with tags, knowing all this.

Your config looks correct and should work unless there is a typo in your actual config. You may want to this out if you want (which is more elegant but same as what you did)
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - if: 'kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum'
      target_label: foo
      replacement: 3

Another thing I noticed is, if statement is misaligned in your example but that should give syntax errors anyways but keep it aligned like this (which is as per the docs) ->
scrape_configs:
- job_name: "kafka_exporter"
  file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - kafka_exporter.yml
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - if: '{__name__="kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum"}'
    target_label: foo
    replacement: 3


It bouth recomends doesnt worked :(
Ironically that everything works in http://my-vm-agent.com:9090/metric-relabel-debug
But does not really work

I found the pattern. Tags are added to all metric after the selected (in example: kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum). Please see "p.s." in question.

@zentkhv that sounds like a bug. Try different version of VictoriaMetrics locally and see if it works otherwise
